# Videoview does not play video in below API level 14

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-video-player, android-videoview

I'm developing application which plays video in videoview. Everything seems fine. But when i am trying to play video in Android 3.2(API 13), it shows blank screen and popups the message - "Can't play this video" and it works perfectly in any other device which have more than API level 13. Here is my code snippet if anyone could help me.

```
VideoView videoView;
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

And in Logcat it shows error information that `MediaPlayer path is null` which is not null actually. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try the examples mentioned on these links:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/
http://androidexample.com/Play_Video_File_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=124&aaid=144

http://blog.brightinventions.pl/frame-video-view/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Also, you don't really say why you believe those links will address the specific problem.

Comment: My only reason to mention those links were so that you can check if they might have given some specific solution to it or you might have missed something in your code.. I haven't tried VideoView to be honest just was helping with some helps... My bad it couldnt help